# Will deleting a user from an on-prem Active Directory affect their Azure Profile?

Tags: azure-active-directory, active-directory

We have one user in our organization that was added to an on-prem active directory before we decided to go with Azure Active Directory and not use the on prem DC.

We're trying to get rid of that on-prem DC but we want to make sure we don't completely screw up this user's profile when we delete it from the on-prem AD. Will this be a problem at all, and if so, how do we remedy this?

Comment: That depends on if your on-prem AD is setup to synchronize with Azure.

Comment: fyi - wrong site for this. I suggest posting to [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how the on-prem AD is synced up with the online AD.
If there exists a sync between the on-prem and the online AD, then deleting the user from the on-prem would delete the migrated user profile from the online AD also.